# How to send arrays with std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray and std_msgs/Float64MultiArray?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I woul like to send arrays to a node, I've tried with this code, but I think there is something wrong when I try to copy the array values in the data structure...

```
uint8_t SSS_ground_unito[doppio_bins]={0};
immagine::pixel_ned messaggio;
double point_seabed_n[doppio_bins]={0};
double point_seabed_e[doppio_bins]={0};

//funzione per inviare il messaggio al nuovo nodo
void send_immagine(uint8_t SSS_grnd_unito[],double point_sbed_n[], double point_sbed_e[]){
    messaggio.pixel.data=SSS_ground_unito;
    messaggio.nord.data=point_seabed_n;
    messaggio.est.data=point_seabed_e;
    cout <<"send"<< messaggio.pixel.data<<endl;
    write_Out.publish(messaggio);//pubblica il messaggio sul topic 
    ROS_INFO("ping inviato");
 }
```

this is my msg

```
std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray  pixel
std_msgs/Float64MultiArray nord
std_msgs/Float64MultiArray est
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393285/how-to-send-arrays-with-std_msgs/uint8multiarray--and-std_msgs/float64multiarray?/) by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2021-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `data` fields of `pixel`, `nord`, and `est` are all `std::vector`, and must therefore have array elements allocated with either `.resize()` (see [this](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/)) or by using `.push_back()` (see [this](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/)).

Both ways will require your code to know how many array elements to expect in the input arguments to the `send_immagine` function. If you know there are `N` elements in the input arrays, you could use `.resize(N)` on each `data` field to allocate the required number of array elements, then copy each input array element into the corresponding vector element.

Alternatively, loop over the input array and call `.push_back()` once for each element.

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2021-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0